# How to enable docker restarts on an error, but not on a host machine reboot

Tags: docker

I've taken a look at the restart policies present for docker containers, and it seemed like `on-failure` would be relevant here. From the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy):

```
on-failure        Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests as a non-zero exit code.
```

From this, it seems like on a host machine reboot, the Docker containers should not come up, as they did not exit of their own accord and throw an exit code of `1`. But upon reboot, I see the containers come up again. To explain the scenario a bit, I want the containers to restart if there is an error, so my application can continue functioning with little interruption. However, on a reboot, there is a specific set of things I need to get done before the containers are up and announce they are ready (to other parts of the system).

My questions can be boiled down to:

1. Are the containers actually throwing an exit code of `1` when they are being stopped when the machine reboots?
2. Is what I am seeing actually the expected behavior of `on-failure`, even if the containers are not throwing an exit code of `1`?

Comment: How is the reboot being done? It sounds like the reboot is causing a KILL signal that prematurely terminates the container, which can constitute as an error. Also by your explanation, it will restart. An exit code of 1 indicates an error, not a success.

Comment: @alex067 reboot is being done through the normal OS reboot call. And yeah, I'm aware that means it's an error, but I may have been incorrectly assuming it returned a 0 when doing a clean reboot.